# using javascript in selenium javascript executor

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to verify if my required text is appearing on page. i cant use selenium webdriver's `gettext()` method as its throwing permission exception. so i am using javascript to compare the text.

```
 String scriptToExec = "var result = document.getElementsByClassName('Sender');
    for(var element in result){
    if (element.text.contains('mytext'))
    {return true;}
    else
    {return false;}}";          

    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    Boolean result = (Boolean) (js.executeScript(scriptToExec));
```

I am getting this exception: org.openqa.selenium.remote.

**`ErrorHandler` $UnknownServerException: element.text is undefined**

Comment: Please give the code and the related stacktrace when you tried the gettext() method. It is supposed to work.

Comment: Cant paste the entire stack trace: Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, webdriver.remote.sessionid=83461874-001e-486f-88a3-5fd82fe125ad, version=26.0, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]

Answer (score 1):

Many JavaScript issues here as well as a severe lack of understanding about selectors. `contains` isn't part of the standard and won't work with older browsers:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains

If there is `element.text` is undefined for whatever reason, you'll need to cope with that:

```
if (element && element.text && element.text.contains('mytext'))
```

(meaning, if "element" is *something* and element.text is *something* and if element.text contains 'mytext')

Also, I can see you are basically trying to do a contains search on some text - you absolutely **do not need JavaScript** for this. It can be done using an XPath selector!

Comment: The contains method is giving me the proper result when executed on firebug console with same browser. Regarding xpath selector i have  mentioned that i am getting a permission related error and that's the reason for using javascript. It seems to me as a syntax related issue. still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Of course Firebug will allow you to do it, it's an addon. You should be working towards fixing the permissions error and not working around it. It's likely it'll keep appearing as you progress through with these automated tests, and so you will just be working *against* the API and basically just using native JS all the time. Fix the issue!